# Wicket session stored in database

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

Is it possible to store Wicket session data in database (of any kind)? For example in MySQL, Redis, MongoDB? Or to persist data on filesystem between restarts of application server?

I'm mainly interested because when developing, it's a pain after restarting application server to log in again, again and again.

Answer (score 2):

about login again and again, my approach is check if wicket is in development mode then pass the login with a test user.

however the JSESSIONID is generated by the servlet container not by the  wicket framework.

[Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created)

in apache tomcat you can do something like 
[How to generate custom JSESSIONID, based on some hash of user's data in order to replicate session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833861/how-to-generate-custom-jsessionid-based-on-some-hash-of-users-data-in-order-to)

Comment: So sessions are managed by application server, not application if I understand it correctly? I use Jetty for development, there seems to be a plugin http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22jetty-session-redis%22 I'll investigate if it is usable. Thank you.