# Hostname in tomcat cookies

Tags: java, session, tomcat, hostname

Our Tomcat creates session IDs with the following format:

jsessionid=a345465820fce654354646ae.(server-name);

Is it possible to configure it so that server-name is not part of session id?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement your own session manager to change the format of `JSESSIONID`. I am not sure what you want to achieve but this question might be of interest, you also have a link to the session manager HOW-TO at Tomcat.

[How to generate custom JSESSIONID, based on some hash of user's data in order to replicate session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833861/how-to-generate-custom-jsessionid-based-on-some-hash-of-users-data-in-order-to)

However, if you have an Apache server in front of your Tomcat it might be easier to create your own cookie and use that instead of `JSESSIONID`. You can do this by using the [mod_header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) and there is an example of this in the [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#example) documentation.

Hope it helps you forward.

Comment: @j_maly I guess this did not work for you. What was the problem?